# I/O error when burning Windows OS to DVD from Image Burn tool

Tags: disk-image, io

I get the error message below from Imageburn when I try to burn Windows OS to a blank DVD.

I want to know whether the cause might be the DVD writer or something else?

I tried two blank discs. But I get the same error.

[image: error message]

Comment: What kind of DVD do you have? Is it compatible with your burner? IIRC, there are two types, DVD+ and DVD-.

Comment: I get above error half way of writing. on my disc it says DVD-R brand is AL 16x4.75GB 120 min

Comment: However, the dvd are older than 1 year.

Comment: It would have been better if you copy-pasted the full log to a site such as Pastebin instead of just a screenshot of the dialog. If reducing the burn speed doesn't help and you're sure the drive's working fine, switch to better quality media such as genuine Verbatim or Taiyo Yuden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message, you seem to have [this DVD writer](http://www.cdrinfo.com/Sections/Reviews/Specific.aspx?ArticleId=24562), the SH-S223F.

Its maximum writing speed might exceed the one supported by your DVD (22X against 16X).

Since speed usually [increases the farther you go from the DVD center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_linear_velocity), at the beginning you'll be burning at lower speed, and everything will be OK.

As soon as the actual speed exceeds the DVD rating, though, an error will likely occur (or even worse, the DVD might turn out to be faulty or "unstable" -- i.e., a few weeks out in the daylight and it will start losing sectors.

If at all possible, try setting Image Burn to not detect maximum speed (as this operation is sometimes unreliable) but force it to go at a fixed speed of 16X (or 8X, if you don't mind the wait).

Sometimes, it also happens that DVD purported to be "16X" are actually lower speed. If you don't fill it up completely, with a bit of luck you *might* never know that a 16X DVD was actually a cheaper 12X (I had this happen with a whole spindle - fifty of them. And since I use them for backup, I *always* fill them up completely).